# Symfony 4 Forms: implementing per-Entity custom sorting in QueryBuilder for ChoiceType fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I seem to have some troubles getting my head around the intrinsics of the Symfony (4) Form component.

I want to:

a) store information per-Entity(Repository?) on how the default sort order should be, like $entityRepository->sortOrder = ['default' => ['LastName ASC', 'FirstName ASC'], 'custom1' => [...]];

b) use that information to instruct the Form to use that ordering with the query_builder option/attribute for the ChoiceType form field

So the question is, how/where should i ideally store that information and how should i feed this to the Form object / QueryBuilder?

Pointing me in a direction doing it in a "industry-standard" fashion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony Forms comes with an `EntityType` that allows you to specify a custom query:

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder

If the ordering is specific to the form, you might want to build the query inline in your form (like in the example of the link above). If the same ordering of an entity applies to multiple forms, extract it into a method in your repository and use the method when building the custom query in the form type.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I seem to have missed that part of symfony documentation.
For the sub question, where would you suppose its best to store the ordering information, i suppose the Entity itself is not a good place? Better an EntityRepository attribute like this entityRepository->sortOrder = ['default' => ['LastName ASC', 'FirstName ASC'], 'custom1' => [...]];?

Comment: It depends. If the association should always be ordered that way, you may use Doctrine's `OrderBy` feature (see [Doctrine Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_orderby)). If it's just in the form, do it in the form type like in the example in the Symfony docs I linked in my answer.